# Geocode call returns no results or status

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding

This code gives no error messages in the chrome developer console. The debugger shows the value that I expect being passed to the Geocode method.

It fails on the call to geocode and goes right to the end of the function as soon as it hits that line. The debugger cannot even show a value for the result variable, and the status variable has a value of "".

This code used to work fine. Don't know what I did to break it. Do I need to uri encode addressVal before passing it or does the geocode method do that? A second pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

```
function geoCode(ID) {
    var addresses = $("#" + ID).find(".address");
    var addressVal = $(addresses[0]).val();
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressVal }, function (results, status) {
    var getStatus = status;
    var result = (results[0]);
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && result) {
        mylat = result.geometry.location.lat();
        mylng = result.geometry.location.lng();
    }

    if (ID == "#generalInfo") {
        updateOwner();
    }
    else if (ID == "#newLocationInput") {
        addEstablishments();
    }
    else if($(ID).hasClass('locationItem')) {
        saveEstablishments(ID);
    }
    //setNumC();
    //checkAddress();

    }
});
```

Comment: Please share the addressVal being passes to the call.

Comment: "52 Swan St, Lowell, MA, United States"

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I will minimize it, but it is complete, test, readable. I have fully vetted thyis in the debugger so I am not here to waste people['s time without putting in my own effort first. As far as the ID value being passed into it, it is a string representing a section on the page with that ID.

Comment: The posted code is "working" fine for the posted address, it just doesn't do anything useful because you haven't provided the HTML required to run the code that does stuff with the result (that you also haven't provided).

Comment: Please see more simple revised code. It never gets to any of the function calls that effect the html. The debugger clearly shows me that. And those function calls at the end are all tested. But again, that is irrelevant because it never even calls those functions and fails before that

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? The geocoder anonymous function never gets called? `results` is empty? What passes over the wire (geocoder request + response)?

Comment: it fails on geocoder.geocode({ 'address': addressVal }, function (results, status) { and does not execute the callback. As per original explanation, the debugger shows the status variable as "" and it does not even show a value for the results variable at all. It gets to that line and then immediately foes to the end of the function, completely skipping the callback.

Comment: Is the `ID` parameter expected to contain the CSS `#` selector or not? On the first line you look up `$('#'+ID)` but in your `if...else` you are comparing to strings that already contain the `#`

Comment: The ID value passed to Geocode does not contain a #. That's why the code prepends the #. function geoCode(ID) {
    var addresses = $("#" + ID).find(".address");
    var addressVal = $(addresses[0]).val();.

Comment: Hello Thernys. You found the problem. It wasn't stopping on the geocode call, it was bombing at if (ID == "#generalInfo") and it just appeared to be stopping at the geocode call. Since ID had no #, then # shouldn't have been used in the comparison. Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as an answer?

Comment: How were we supposed to tell that?  You didn't provide the HTML you are using...